# Pandas Dataframes not equal though they are

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, equality

I'm running this test using `pandas==1.4.1` and `dython==0.7.1` on Python 3.10.3. I create a simple correlation dataframe from dates data, and compare it to the what I expect to get. Still, according to Pandas, the DFs are not equal, even though they have the same data and same `dtypes`. What am I missing?

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dython.nominal import associations

def test_datetime_data():
    dt = datetime(2020, 12, 1)
    end = datetime(2020, 12, 2)
    step = timedelta(seconds=5)
    result = []
    while dt < end:
        result.append(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        dt += step

    nums = list(range(len(result)))
    df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':result, 'up': nums, 'down': sorted(nums, reverse=True)})
    df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  # without this, this column is considered as object rather than dates

    correct_corr = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dates', 'up', 'down'], index=['dates', 'up', 'down'],
                                data=[[1.0, 1.0, -1.0],
                                      [1.0, 1.0, -1.0],
                                      [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]])
    corr = associations(df, plot=False)['corr']
    assert corr.equals(correct_corr), f'datetime associations are incorrect. Test should have returned an empty dataframe, received: {corr.head()}'
```

Both `corr` and `correct_corr` are `[[1.0, 1.0, -1.0], [1.0, 1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]]` as `float64`, yet the test still fails..

Comment: I'm using `equals` not `compare`. It does give `True` or `False`. Run the code and you'll get the DF.

Comment: What is `associations`?

Comment: Fixed the missing imports, now it should be clear

Comment: I can't reproduce the error (running on WSL2) the only difference is i have py 3.10.4

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the datatypes in the dataframe to make sure that they are the same.

```
corr.info()
correct_corr.info()
```